# HaXml installation issues on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, haskell, haxml

I'm having trouble installing HaXml on my system.

I've installed the Haskell platform and used the clang-wrapper patch provided in the following link : http://www.haskell.org/platform/mac.html

When I try run `cabal install HaXml` I get the following error. I've tried everything I can by doing some research and still have no luck in fixing this issue. I've even tried installing the dependencies found on this link http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml individually and then trying to install the package but still no luck. I get the following error messages in the terminal:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring HaXml-1.24...

/var/folders/m0/w93djnj57fv4wynyrjf4lgxc0000gn/T/23529.c:1:12:
     warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
int foo() {}
           ^
1 warning generated.
Building HaXml-1.24...
Preprocessing library HaXml-1.24...
[ 1 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Xtract.Lex ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Xtract/Lex.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Xtract/Lex.o )
[ 2 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.DtdToHaskell.TypeDef ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/DtdToHaskell/TypeDef.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/DtdToHaskell/TypeDef.o )
[ 3 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.DtdToHaskell.Instance ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/DtdToHaskell/Instance.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/DtdToHaskell/Instance.o )
[ 4 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Posn ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Posn.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Posn.o )
[ 5 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Lex ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Lex.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Lex.o )
[ 6 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Types ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Types.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Types.o )
[ 7 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Namespaces ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Namespaces.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Namespaces.o )
[ 8 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Schema.XSDTypeModel ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Schema/XSDTypeModel.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Schema/XSDTypeModel.o )

src/Text/XML/HaXml/Schema/XSDTypeModel.hs:305:19: Warning:
    Fields of `Schema' not initialised: schema_elementFormDefault,
                                        schema_attributeFormDefault, schema_finalDefault,
                                        schema_blockDefault, schema_targetNamespace, schema_version,
                                        schema_namespaces
    In the expression: Schema {schema_items = []}
    In an equation for `mempty': mempty = Schema {schema_items = []}
    In the instance declaration for `Monoid Schema'
[ 9 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Schema.PrimitiveTypes ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Schema/PrimitiveTypes.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Schema/PrimitiveTypes.o )
[10 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Verbatim ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Verbatim.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Verbatim.o )
[11 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Combinators ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Combinators.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Combinators.o )
[12 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Parse ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Parse.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Parse.o )
[13 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Pretty ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Pretty.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Pretty.o )
[14 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Html.Generate ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Html/Generate.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Html/Generate.o )
[15 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Html.Parse ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Html/Parse.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Html/Parse.o )
[16 of 42] Compiling Text.XML.HaXml.Wrappers ( src/Text/XML/HaXml/Wrappers.hs, dist/build/Text/XML/HaXml/Wrappers.o )

src/Text/XML/HaXml/Wrappers.hs:34:36:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `b0 -> c0'
    Expected type: b0 -> c0
      Actual type: String
    In the return type of a call of `show'
    Probable cause: `show' is applied to too many arguments
    In the first argument of `(.)', namely `show 1'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `show 1 . 24'

src/Text/XML/HaXml/Wrappers.hs:34:36:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `a0 -> c0'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `show 1 . 24'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `"part of HaXml-" ++ show 1 . 24'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      putStrLn $ "part of HaXml-" ++ show 1 . 24
Failed to install HaXml-1.24
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
HaXml-1.24 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see what the problem is, but don't know a great solution.

The problem is in the src/Text/XML/HaXml/Wrappers.hs file.  (FYI, you can always easily view source code in cabal by typing "cabal unpack ", then cd into the newly created directory).  If you look at that file, it is using a ghc language extension to add c style preprocessing to the build before the actual compile.  In this case, it is being used to insert the version number of the build into the source....  Here is the line:

```
putStrLn $ "part of HaXml-"++show MAJOR.MINOR
```

If you then grep through the source code, you can see where the "MAJOR" and "MINOR" macros are being added

```
> grep -r MAJOR *
HaXmL.cabal: cpp-options: -DMAJOR=1 -DMINOR=24
```

This mechanism works fine on my Linux box....  The line in Wrappers.hs expands to

```
putStrLn $ "part of HaXml-"++show 1.24
```

By the error message you have shown above, the expansion on your Mac is actually becoming

```
putStrLn $ "part of HaXml-"++show 1 . 24
```

The difference is subtle, but it has a huge effect.  Because of the extra spaces, instead of parsing the version number as Float, the "." has become the infix composition operator, and it expects "1" and "24" to be functions to compose!

This is probably a bug in the build process....

I don't currently have access to a Mac to debug further (like I mentioned previously, this compiled on my Linux box), but you do have the following options.

1. You could submit a but report to the HaXmL folks, and wait for them to fix it (I may do this myself, If I feel motivated later on today).  Obviously, this could take some time.
2. Work on another OS, if you have that option.
3. If you just want to get things up and running, make a small fix and build it yourself.

This is easier than it sounds.  Just do the following:

```
> cabal unpack HaXmL
> cd HaXmL-1.24
```

Now edit src/Text/XML/HaXml/Wrappers.hs and directly put the version numbers in by hand (ie- change "MAJOR.MINOR" to "1.24") (also src/Text/XML/HaXml.hs).  Continue by typing

```
> cabal configure
> cabal build
> cabal install
```

(These last three lines could be replaced by just the last one "cabal install", but since you are debugging I think it is easier to isolate problems by typing each separately).

If this works, you should have a working version of HaXmL.  Of course this isn't a great solution for the long run (ie- you have to repeat this for every upgrade), but it is sometimes the only way to get going quickly.

Comment: +1 superb effort, great, helpful answer. You are making the internet better.

Comment: Great answer. I fixed this issue locally and submitted a patch to the Malcolm Wallace, the HaXml maintainer. [Here's the patch file](https://gist.github.com/jsl/9036437) if anyone else needs to fix this before it's fixed upstream.